# Add package to Conda Environment from site-packages

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, package, conda, egg

this might be a fundamental misunderstanding of Python packages, but I could use some help or directions to the right resources.

I have a egg file in my Python 3.6 site-packages directory, i'll call it package.egg. When I run python from the command line I can use modules from that package. However, when I created a new Pycharm Project and a corresponding Conda environment, I can no longer use that package (for obvious reasons). However, it doesn't seem like just copying package.egg file into the project environments site files.

Is there another process, like unzipping that I have to perform before I can call those modules?

I tried running both `pip install ./package.egg` and `conda install ./package.egg`

Comment: Why not just reinstall the package into your new environment, just like you installed it in the original environment? Why bother copying/worrying about the particular egg file?

Comment: Thanks @darthbith. This is exactly what I ended up doing, I still have much to learn about how the environments/paths/packages work.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this error by reinstalling the package in the context of the new environment. In this case, through the PyCharm terminal I went back to the packages setup.py file and ran that. It installed the package into the correct location in my conda environment.